# Probability that underlying distribution of random value is centered on 0 or 1

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bayes-theorem

I have two normal distributions $N(0,\sigma)$ and $N(1,\sigma)$, denoted by their density functions $f_0(x)$ and $f_1(x)$.

With probability $\Pr[b=0]$ some "challenger" selects the distribution 0 (with $f_0(x)$), or with probability $\Pr[b=1]=1-\Pr[b=0]$ distribution 1 (with $f_1(x)$); then he randomly outputs a value $y$ according to that distribution.

Now, given this $y$, I want to know the probability that the challenger used distribution 0 for it.

My approach: Using Bayes' theorem I have
$$
\Pr[b=0\;|\;y]=\frac{\Pr[y\;|\;b=0]\Pr[b=0]}{\Pr[y]}
  =\frac{f_0(y)\cdot\Pr[b=0]}{\Pr[b=0]f_0(y)+\Pr[b=1]f_1(y)}.
$$

When plotting this formula the result looks reasonable, but I'm not entirely sure that it is right to directly use the density functions here. So my question is: Is my approach correct?

Edit: I tried to prove it using L'Hospital's rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus:
\begin{align*}
\Pr[b=0\;|\;y]&=\frac{\Pr[b=0]\Pr[y\;|\;b=0]}{\Pr[y]}\\
  &=\lim\limits_{\hat{y}\to y}\frac{\Pr[b=0]\overbrace{\int_{\hat{y}}^{y}f_0(t)\mathrm{d} t}^{\to 0}}{\Pr[b=0]\underbrace{\int_{\hat{y}}^{y}f_0(t)\mathrm{d} t}_{\to 0}+\Pr[b=1]\underbrace{\int_{\hat{y}}^{y}f_1(t)\mathrm{d} t}_{\to 0}}\\
  &=\lim\limits_{\hat{y}\to y}\frac{\Pr[b=0]\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} y}\int_{\hat{y}}^{y}f_0(t)\mathrm{d} t}{\Pr[b=0]\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} y}\int_{\hat{y}}^{y}f_0(t)\mathrm{d} t+\Pr[b=1]\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} y}\int_{\hat{y}}^{y}f_1(t)\mathrm{d} t}\\
  &=\lim\limits_{\hat{y}\to y}\frac{\Pr[b=0]f_0(y)}{\Pr[b=0]f_0(y)+\Pr[b=1]f_1(y)}\\
  &=\frac{\Pr[b=0]f_0(y)}{\Pr[b=0]f_0(y)+\Pr[b=1]f_1(y)}.
\end{align*}
Is that the right proof or is there an error in my reasoning?

Comment: I think the issue is in thinking about whether density values are probabilities; which is something that gets elucidated more when taking classes in [measure theoretic probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory#Measure-theoretic_probability_theory). 

Other than that, in this situation you can use the density, and your model is a [Naive Bayes Classifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), and is the correct approach

Comment: Ah, great, thank you for the clarification and the link! I haven't encountered this notion yet :)